# What's wrong with my Ruby Cipher?

Tags: ruby, encryption, cryptography

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with my code. I am attempting to create a onetime pad cipher, which takes a string scrambles it and then puts it back out. But when I put a string in it doesn't work, can someone correct my work, thanks.

My Work:

```
        h = {}
        v = 0

        ('A'..'Z').each do |c|
        v+=1
         h[c] = v
        end 

        puts "Provide Input:"
        input = gets
        input.downcase!


        if input.include?("a") 
            n = h["A"] + rand(26)
            puts h.index(n) 

        if input.include?("b")
            n = h["B"] + rand(26)
            puts h.index(n) 

        if input.include?("c")
            n = h["C"] + rand(26)
            puts h.index(n)  

        etc, etc... (All the way to the end of the alphabet)
           end
           end
       end
```

Comment: Define “doesn’t work”.

Comment: It does not return the "scrambled" version of the original string, if you use certain strings, it does not return a random "scrambled" version. Sometimes it returns just 1 pseudorandom character.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some before and after examples of what you would *expect* this code to do.

Comment: Well if you don’t provide the whole code then we can‘t know what’s actually happening—or test it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any 'end' trailing each 'if' block.  If that's the case, it means your ifs are nested, and you're only checking the next condition when the previous one is met (won't do anything if there's no 'a', won't do much if there's an 'a' but no 'b', etc).  Also, any time you have chunks of code that are nearly identical and only vary by a small amount, it's typically a sign that there's a much easier way of doing what you want.